# Finding Orthogonality from Eucliean Norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

How to solve this? 
Given A, B and X are three linearly independent 3x1 column vectors. 
  One can find coefficients "a" and "b" such that the Euclidean norm of Y = X-a*A-b*B is minimized. Which of the following are true? 
1. Y and X are orthogonal, i.e., their dot product is zero  
2. Y and A are orthogonal  
3. Y and B are orthogonal   
4. Euclidean norm of Y is always zero

Comment: Is there any restriction for a and b to be non-zero?

Comment: The question didn't mention any restriction.